# Как вставить ник в чат?

Tags: javascript

Есть небольшой чат , вывод через фрейм, нужна помощь дописать функцию onclick тоесть если нужно ответить человеку и чтоб занести например его имя из вывода в текстарея есть такая функция
Типа вот так
[image: area]

```js
function enter_user(n)
{
    document.getElementById('chat').focus();
    document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML=n+', ';
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick="enter_user('[b #]bridun[/b] ')">bridun</a>

<textarea type="text" name="chat" id="chat"  /></textarea>
```

но оно срабатывает один раз тоесть нажал ответил кому то а если кому то еще раз отвечать уже не заноситься в текстарею а нужна перезагрузка страницы как с этим справиться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Менять можно используя value, потому что innerHTML меняет содержимое, но не показывает изменений во второй раз и далее

```js
function enter_user(n) {
    document.getElementById('chat').focus();
    document.getElementById('chat').value = n+', ';
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick="enter_user('[b]bridun[/b]')">bridun</a>

<textarea type="text" name="chat" id="chat"  /></textarea>
```